# Code inside a function works, but the function itself doesn't

Tags: r, function

Let's assume I have this dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(A = letters[1:5],
                B = letters[6:10],
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  A B
1 a f
2 b g
3 c h
4 d i
5 e j
```

Where I'm looking for this output:

```
  A B
1 e j
2 d i
3 c h
4 b g
5 a f
```

With this function:

```
f_Order <- function(df){
  df$Order <- as.integer(row.names(df))
  df <- arrange(df, desc(Order))[,c("A","B")]
}
```

Though the function above doesn't work, the code inside the function works perfectly:

```
df$Order <- as.integer(row.names(df))
df <- arrange(df, desc(Order))[,c("A","B")]
> x
  A B
1 e j
2 d i
3 c h
4 b g
5 a f
```

Why? How do I make the function work?

**EDIT:**

To clarify, the problem statement is **not** to change the order of the df, but to make the function `f_Order` to work. The code does what I want, but it doesn't what I want inside that function. I need to know why, and how I can make the function to work.

**EDIT2:**

This is exactly the code I'm running, and still doesn't work any of the solutions.

```
x <- data.frame(A = letters[1:5],
                B = letters[6:10],
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

f_Order <- function(df){
  df$Order <- as.integer(row.names(df))
  df <- arrange(df, desc(Order))
  return(df)
}
f_Order(x)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use dplyr programming syntax to create and evaluate variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53859015/how-to-use-dplyr-programming-syntax-to-create-and-evaluate-variable-names)

Comment: I don't see how that question is at least similar to mine @NelsonGon

Comment: `dplyr` based functions use `quasiquotation` which is what is used in the answers to the above question.

Comment: The expected output is the df starting with `e` and `j`. I put an example in the question. My second edit gives you the desired output? Because it doesn't give it to me the desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you have a `return()` at the end of your function? Something like this:

```
f_Order <- function(df){
  df$Order <- as.integer(row.names(df))
  df <- arrange(df, desc(Order))[,c("A","B")]
  return(df)
}
```

Basically if you have stuff happening in a function, you need to return it at the end if you want there to be an output. Otherwise it just...does it inside the function, but not in the wider environment, and then doesn't show you anything.

Output:

```
> f_Order(df)
  A B
1 e j
2 d i
3 c h
4 b g
5 a f
```

If you want to update df, then run `df <- f_Order(df)`.

Comment: I understand it. I just need the changes (not the return). But I still don't get why it works for you and not for me.

Comment: That's because in your function you don't return a value, instead, you just assign to a variable `df`, which will live only inside the function, not outside. With `return(df)` you will return an object that will live outside of the function.

Comment: If you have the `return()` in there then you can do something like `df <- f_Order(df)` to make the changes stick.

Comment: Instead of  `f_Order(x)`, have `x <- f_Order(x)`. That will change `x` to be the version with the function applied.

Comment: Lol. It was so simple. And I was wondering if I would have to update the R version haha. Thanks!

Comment: @RLave - The function as they had it did return a value. It did so invisibly though so would either need to explicitly printed or stored and then viewed later.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing with `dplyr`:

```
f_Order <- function(df){
  #df$Order <- as.integer(row.names(df))
  df %>% 
    mutate(Order=row.names(.)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Order))
}
```

If we don't want to keep `Order`:

```
 f_Order <- function(df){

      df %>% 
         arrange(desc(row.names(.)))
    }
```

Result:

```
f_Order(df)
   A B
1 e j
2 d i
3 c h
4 b g
5 a f
```